# reactjs, putting n options together in a select

Tags: reactjs

I have the following piece of jsx in my reactjs program,

```
<select onChange = {this.selectChange}>
  <option>{this.state.array[0]}</option>
  <option>{this.state.array[1]}</option>
  <option>{this.state.array[2]}</option>
  <option>{this.state.array[3]}</option>
</select>
```

Its actually much longer than this, I have 32 elements in the array so I'd like to find a more compact way of doing this. For example, I was thinking something like this:

```
<select onChange = {this.selectChange}>
  {for (var n=0; n<32; n++) <option>{this.state.array[n]}</option>}
</select>
```

However that doesn't work. How might I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const options = this.state.array.map(op => {
    return <option>{op}</option>
  });

  return (
    <select onChange = {this.selectChange}>
      {options}
    </select>
  );
```

To improve readability, you can separate them into another variable `options`, then within that variable using a map function to generate individual item.

To answer your question, your way doesn't work is because there is missing `return` key

Answer (score 1):

usually best to just use a map:

```
<select onChange = {this.selectChange}>
  {this.state.array.map(item => (
    <option>{item}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

The reason the for loop version is not working is because jsx doesn't know how to parse a for loop correctly because it would have to connect 2 disparate jsx blocks (because of the squiggly bracket block that would need to be accounted for).